# Calculating the power of a number faster than O(m)

Tags: algorithm

How can I calculate a power of a number, let's say n^m, using fewer multiplication? Is the brute force(**n * n * n * n * ... * n**) the only solution to this problem? I want to reduce the complexity from **O(m)** to logarithmic at least.

**EDIT:**
I found that there is a *recursive* solution, where from a bigger power(let's say 8), you can use powers already calculated that summed up my power(for 8, I can use 4 and 4, where n^4 is already calculated once).

Comment: Use logarithms. 2^5 = antilog(5 * log(2)).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: 2^5 = 2 << (5-1)

Comment: @JorgeY. This is more simple: `1 << (n)`. It also works with 2^0

Comment: @FeiXiang Sure, but I wanted to let the 2 and the 5 in the second expression so the user asking could see how those two expressions are related. Anyway, it was a tricky suggestion, as it only works when you have a power o 2, it would not work with 5^3.

Comment: @JorgeY. Yeah. For that, you probably need to look at some math formulas. Not sure why I put the parenthesis there now that I look at it. should have been `1 << n`.

Answer (score -1):

Fast exponentiation is *x^(2n) = (x^n)^2*, and *x^(2n+1) = (x^n)^2.x* which leads to logarithmic complexity (at each step you divide the exponent by 2).